# Recover Data from .bak File

Tags: sql-server, restore

I could use tips on how to recover a non-standard SQL Server `.bak` backup file, please.

The background: we have a functioning invoicing program with over 10 years of data from a defunct provider. In past correspondence, the provider told us that the product was built on SQL Server, but never told us what version.

Our goal is to export the data from the program, reformat it, and then load it into another accounting system. The program itself does not have a complete set of export tools so we are hoping to access the data from the `.bak` files it creates to get all the data for importing into the new system.

I have tried the following SQL Server versions without success:

- 2000
- 2005
- 2008
- 2008 R2
- 2012
- 2014
- 2016
- 2017

I have also tried recovering with...

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 but no backup sets are listed for restoration
- SysTools SQL Backup recovery but it returns "Could not identify SQL Server version for the selected .bak file."
- SQL Server 2017 on a Linux machine and get the following output...

```
1> restore database newhouse from disk='/home/me/test.bak'
2> go
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
The media family on device '/home/me/test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
1> restore verifyonly from disk='/home/me/test.bak'
2> go
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
The media family on device '/home/me/test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
1> restore headeronly from disk='/home/me/test.bak' with nounload
2> go
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
The media family on device '/home/me/test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
1> restore headeronly from disk='/home/me/test.bak' 
2> go
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
The media family on device '/home/me/test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1
```

A `.bak` file with fictitious data [is available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iw98z4dtw4fh9if/test.bak?dl=0).

---

**Update #1** - in reply @DavidJamesSmith

Here is what I get...

```
1> restore headeronly 
2> from disk = N'/home/me/test.bak' 
3> go 
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1 
The media family on device '/home/me/test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family. 
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 8350, Line 1 
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
```

**Update #2** - again in reply @DavidJamesSmith

From what I can tell, the file is ***not*** encrypted. I can open the file with gHex - a hex editor in GNOME - and read the data.

As far as the question about the file being corrupted, I do not believe so. I get the same error on any `.bak` file created by this program whether the `.bak` file is on the machine that create the `.bak` or on another machine that I have transferred the file to.

If the file is corrupted, than the program itself is exporting a corrupted version.

Here is what I get on a fresh export running on the machine that has the account software itself.

```
1> use newhouse
2> restore database newhouserecovery from
3> disk = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\test.bak'
4> with
5> file = 1,
6> move N'test' to N'C:\Users\me\Backup\test.mdf',
7> move N'test_log' to N'C:\Users\me\Backup\test_log.ldf',
8> nounload,
9> stats = 5
10> go
Changed database context to 'newhouse'.
Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server DESKTO\SQLEXPRESS, Line 2
The media family on device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\test.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server DESKTO\SQLEXPRESS, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Try the query here https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/03/17/sql-server-identify-version-of-sql-server-from-backup-file/

Comment: It is possible your backup files are corrupted or perhaps encrypted. Are you able to contact your old provider to confirm if they were encrypted and if so if they can provide the key / certificate?

Comment: Try this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37288/media-family-on-device-is-incorrectly-formed-sql-server-cannot-process-this-med

Comment: @DavidJamesSmith - See reply under Update #2 above

Comment: Can you not just the Export Data / Import Data tools from SSMS to export 'schema + data' then load those scripts instead of trying to use a backup atall. Right click the database name -> Tasks -> Export Data -> Advanced -> Schema + Data

Comment: @SurajKumar - I have not been successful in figuring out how to find the present instance of the MS SQL that is supporting the old accounting software that we are trying to retire. I can see the process for the instance of the accounting software, but not any other processes point to a MS SQL instance.

Comment: @Milney - I have not been able to find the actual instance that the accounting software is using so that was why I was trying to use a .bak file.

Comment: You could try sqlserver compact/ce

Comment: @user371793 You can use the netstat command or the Network tab on resource monitor to detect with host it is connecting to on the MSSQL port, that will show you where the instance is located

Comment: @lptr - Thanks for the tip. That is a database version I did not know about and proved to be platform that was being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account software was using Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2.

Thanks for everyone's help and, especially @lptr for the tip that got me going down the correct track.